# Manipulate string in python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am scraping web content with Beautifulsoup, Python and I would like to manipulate the following strings:

```
'Induktora  28" 36V/14 Ah | 16.5" Bordo'
'Induktora  28" 36V/14 Ah | 18" Bordo'
'Induktora  26" 36V/14 Ah | 16.5" Black Matte/Red' 
'Induktora  26" 36V/14 Ah | 18" Black Matte/Red'
```

I would like to get:

- word after "`|`" and contains quote at the end `"`
- word(s) after "`|`" and after the quote `"` (if there is any)

Example:

```
str='Induktora  28" 36V/14 Ah | 16.5" Bordo'
size='16.5"'
color='Bordo'
newtitle='Induktora  28" 36V/14 Ah'


str='Induktora  26" 36V/14 Ah | 18" Black Matte/Red'
size='18"'
color='Black Matte/Red'
newtitle='Induktora  26" 36V/14 Ah'
```

Comment: Show your own effort (code). There is https://regex101.com to play around with regular expressions (set to Python flavor).

Comment: You can do it without regex quite easily. Is there a reason to prefer regex over plain old `str.split` and `str.find`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd probably use the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module for that. Your pattern would probably look something like `\| ([\d\.]+)" (.*)$`.

If your regex pattern isn't doing what you expect, you can debug it at a site like https://pythex.org/.